# Range of $|x+3|+|x-3|=6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can solve this equation by som tedious algebra, I got $x_1=3$ and $x_2=-3$. But according to the book the solutions are given by $x\in[-3,3]$, which means that for example $x=1$ and $x=2$ are solutions as well. How can I algebraically show this? Or can I interpret the absolutes as distances along the x-axis and somehow proceed from there?

Comment: what's $x_1{}$?

Comment: Just indexing the different roots with 1 and 2.

Comment: But the equation has infinitely many solutions....

Comment: Yes, infinitely many between $x=-3$ and $x=3$. But how would one solve this on an exam? When I solved it I just got the roots above, but I could not show that the numbers between are roots too.

Comment: Could you show us a bit of such tedious algebra?

Comment: $|x+3|=6-|x-3|$ so for $x>-3$ we have $x+3=6-|x-3|\Leftrightarrow |x-3|=x+3.$ Then just do the same reasoning again and again. I'm not sure why you want me to re-do the tedious work? It's even more tedious to do here with latex coding.

Comment: @Parseval If you only got the two solutions $\pm 3$, then you must have made an error somewhere, and perhaps one of us could help you find it.

Comment: Intuition: the distance to $-3$ plus the distance to $3$ is equal to $6$.

Comment: @MarkBennet The distance to -3 from where? That doesnt seem logical. Choosing x=10 we get that the distance from 10 to -3 is 13. Distance from 10 to 3 is 7. Adding we get 13+7=20.

Comment: @Parseval Quite. So $10$ doesn't satisfy the inequality. Which points do have total distance = $6$? I find that the intuition about distance helps me to think about absolute values. It is especially helpful when I get to complex numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you consider the interval $[-3,3]$ (whose total length is $6$) and pick a point $x$ in that interval, then $|x-3|+|x+3|$ is the sum of the distances of this point from the two end-points $\pm 3$. But this sum is simply the length of the interval (which is $6$ as mentioned above) hence every point in the interval is a solution.

If you pick $x$ outside the interval $[-3,3]$, then it's distance from one of the end points (depending on which side $x$ is) will already be greater than $6$, hence the equality cannot occur for points outside the interval.

Comment: Mention that $|x-a|$ is the nonnegative distance from x to a. they taught most of us in elementary school that |x| is the distance from x to 0

Comment: @SakethMalyala OP has already mentioned in the statement "absolute distances" so I am quite hopeful that he is well aware of the usage of the word distance in my answer.

Comment: oh, i didn't see that. thanks!

Comment: This is a great explanation. So easy to understand, I can now in my head see exactly why the answer is $x\in[-3,3].$ Thank you buddy!

Answer (score 2):

More mechanically: for each of the three ranges $x<-3$, $x\in[ -3, 3]$, and $x>3$, simplify the expressions involving absolute value signs.  For instance, when $x<-3$, you have $|x+3|+|x-3| = (-x-3) + (-x +3) = -2x$.  On $[-3,3]$ you have $|x+3| = x+3$ but $|x-3| = 3-x$, so $|x+3|+|x-3| = 6$ there.  And similarly for $x>3$, resulting in $2x$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x<-3$:
$$|x+3|+|x-3|=-(x+3)-(x-3)=-2x>6\implies\text{no solutions}$$
If $x>3$:
$$|x+3|+|x-3|=x+3+x-3=2x>6\implies \text{no solutions}$$
If $-3\leq x\leq 3$:
$$|x+3|+|x-3|=x+3-(x-3)=6\implies \text{true}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$|x+3|=\begin{cases}
x+3, & \text{ if } x\geq -3\\
-x-3,& \text{ if } x<-3
\end{cases}$$
and 
$$|x-3|=\begin{cases}
x-3, & \text{ if } x> 3\\
-x+3,& \text{ if } x\leq3
\end{cases}$$

Thus,
$$|x+3|+|x-3|=\begin{cases}
2x, & \text{ if } x> 3\\
6, &\text{ if }-3 \leq x \leq3\\
-2x,& \text{ if } x<-3
\end{cases}$$

When $x>3$, then $2x>6.$ Similarly if $x<-3,$ then $-2x>6.$

Thus, the set of solutions is $[-3,3].$

Answer (score 2):

If you want to solve this kind of equations more or less methodically, you have to consider in separate cases the possible signs of the expressions inside the absolute value.

1. Let $x>3$.

Then $x-3>0$ and $x+3>0$, so $|x+3|+|x-3|=(x+3)+(x-3)=2x$, and the only solution to $|x+3|+|x-3|=6$ is $2x=6$, or $x=3$. But this is outside the range $x>3$, so it must be disregarded.

2. Let $x<3$.

Now both expressions are negative and, as before, there is no solution.

3. Let $x\in[-3,3]$.

Then $x+3\ge0$ and $x-3\le 0$, so $|x+3|+|x-3|=(x+3)-(x-3)=6$. In other words, for every point in this interval the equation holds, so the solution is the interval $[-3,3]$.

Answer (score 2):

........................................

[image]

.........................................

Answer (score 1):

By triangle inequality we have:
$$|x+3|+|x-3| = |x+3|+|3-x|\geq |x+3+3-x| = 6$$
and equality is achived when $x+3$ and $3-x$ are of equal sign.

So $x+3\geq 0$ and $3-x\geq 0$ so $x\in [-3,3]$

or  $x+3< 0$ and $3-x< 0$ which is impossible.

Comment: How did you see that "equality is achieved when $x+3$ and $3-x$ are of equal signs"?

Comment: Do you know triangle inequality?

Comment: Yes: $|x|+|y|\geq |x+y|.$

Comment: Ok, I see why your statement is correct now!